# How to call a function after the setting the state

Tags: react-native

I am setting state to some variables but what happens is when I call `onSub()` for the first time nothing happens and when I call it for second time the values from the first call reflects and so on. What should I do?

```
onSub(){
   this.setState({price:[...this.state.price,this.state.tprice],
           Quantity:[...this.state.Quantity,this.state.tQuantity],
          ItemName:[...this.state.ItemName,this.state.tItemName]
        })
this.afterCall();}

afterCall(){
       //i is Declared Globally
for(;i<this.state.price.length; i++){

   price.push(<View key={i}><Text style={{paddingLeft:5}}> 
   {this.state.price[i]}</Text></View>) 

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it takes time for the state to be set, `this.setState` takes a call back, which will be run once the state has been set. You can use it like this

```
this.setState({ //set your item to state }, () => this.afterCall());
```

You can read more about it here https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296

Comment: but when I added an another set state at the end of for loop it is working for me can you explain me why? and Thank you for your answer @Andrew

Comment: Because when you setState it causes the a re-render